# Tridion not publishing after a content port

Tags: tridion

I've done an allegedly successful Content Port between two Content Manager servers.  Now when attempting to Publish the pages, I'm getting the error below on all pages.

```
(5) Invalid procedure call or argument
Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:54-18445-64).
Unable to read Page (tcm:54-18445-64).

URLConversion.PostProcessLocationInfo
PageBLST.Read
XMLState.GetXML
Page.GetXML
UtilitiesPublish.RenderPage
Page.Render
Request.Render
```

Even when attempting to open the pages in the Content Manager, I still get the error "Invalid Remote Procedure Call"

Using the direct TCM links in IE, I get the following for the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<tcm:Error Severity="1" Source="Kernel" Category="7" ErrorCode="5" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">-<tcm:Line ErrorCode="5" MessageID="16137" Cause="false">
<![CDATA[Unable to read Page (tcm:54-18445-64).]]>
<tcm:Token>RESID_4553</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_4442</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:54-18445-64</tcm:Token></tcm:Line>-<tcm:Line ErrorCode="5" Cause="true">
<![CDATA[Invalid procedure call or argument]]>
</tcm:Line>-<tcm:Details>-<tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>URLConversion.PostProcessLocationInfo</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>PageBLST.Read</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLState.GetXML</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Page.GetXML</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>
```

UPDATE:

DB extract as below for a page which wouldn't open properly

```
ID  ITEM_TYPE   ITEM_REFERENCE_ID   VERSION TITLE   SCHEMA_REFERENCE_ID APPROVAL_STATUS_ID  PUBLICATION_ID  CONTENT REVISION    TRUSTEE_ID  MODIFICATION_DATE   USER_COMMENT    SYSTEM_COMMENT  BINARY_ID   BINARY_SIZE FILE_NAME   IS_EXTERNAL_BINARY  PAGE_TEMPLATE_REF_ID    COMPONENT_PROCESS   FILE_EXT    PRIORITY    IS_SIMPLE   NAMESPACE_URI   ROOT_ELEMENT    SUB_TYPE    ALLOWED_ON_PAGE PUBLISH_TO_REPOSITORY   METADATA_SCHEMA_REFERENCE_ID    METADATA_XML    DYNAMIC_TEMPLATE    OUTPUT_FORMAT   DESCRIPTION KEY_VALUE   IS_ABSTRACT IS_ROOT
32638   64  18517   0   Web.sitemap NULL    -1  54  <tcm:ComponentPresentations xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"/> 0   14  2012-06-15 15:21:21.927     RESID_16442 NULL    NULL    Web NULL    8303    NULL    NULL    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Aren't you mr positive? :) Does this page exist (tcm:54-18445-64)? is it perhaps an hard-coded url in your code somehow?

Comment: Upvoted for the added details (and for removing the snide, but familiar, Content Porter rant).

Answer (score 3):

You probably had a failed item somewhere, and the CP has left an odd pointer in one of your templates somewhere instead of a URI. Is this occurring with all pages or just some?

You might try opening one of the pages with the protocol handler (type the URI of the page into Internet Explorer on the CMS server) and look for any odd reference pointers. I don't recall the exact format, but they normally have several Cs and Ps in them. If you find some, perhaps post the XML here so we can help further.

Often importing the items a second time can fix any issues cause by circular references.

You say the port was successful, but did you check the log files to look for any warnings?

Comment: Hi Chris,  there's nothing in the log file, 8406 items exported successfully is just about all there is.  Trying to go to the tcm straight in IE on the server results in the same RPC error that I get from Tridion (I've updated the original question to show the output)

Comment: I think you last resort is to try looking for the Page XML in the Tridion_CM database. Take a look in the items table for your page, and let us know what you see. 

NOTE: Digging around in the database is not supported, and should be avoided, so it may be worth contacting Customer Support first, and see if they have any ideas.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for you reply.  I've updated the original post with an example of a Page that won't open from the dbo.Items table.

Comment: The version and revision of the item in the database are both set to 0. Could it be that the item was created but somehow not checked in? Can you find it in the list of checked out items in the GUI?

Comment: Hi Quirijn, I can find the Page in the GUI, it's not showing as checked out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any DWT extensions method? It seems like you have not migrate your DWT Extension dlls new system.
Are you able to preview your pages successfully?

Comment: hi Ram, no we're not using DWT.